# css3 selector issues : hover effect another element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to have a hover effect over one element of my page and the effect happen to an image that is not a child of the hovered element.

Some html

```
<img id="background" src="image.jpg" />
<div id="container">
     <div id="bar"></div>
</div>

<style>
   #background{
       position:fixed;
       top:0;
       left:0;
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
    }
    #bar:hover + #background{
        /* apply some sexy css3 to the background image */
    }

    /* 
          tried #bar:hover ~#background
    */

</style>
```

So the idea is when hovering your cursor over div#bar I would apply a greyscale effect to the image, but I can't seem to get the selector to work :( this makes me a sad puppy

any help appreciated and thank you in advance :)

Comment: Unfortunately with DOM traversal, you can't move up and backwards. The selector you have set up would need to have #background AFTER #bar, in #container, in the DOM

Comment: bugger - to my old friend jQuery I go then :)

Comment: @kunalbhat: CSS selectors are not "DOM traversal". You can move in any direction with DOM traversal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="bar"></div>
     <img id="background" src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

"#container" can not be position:absolute or position:relative or it will effect your position:fixed; position.

Comment: A comment about why this solution which works was downvoted would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't alter the DOM that way. You'd need to go the jQuery route.
Example below:

```
$('#bar').hover(
    $('#background').css('fancy-css'); // do something
);
```

or if you want to run individual functions for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, do this...

```
$('#bar').hover(
    function() {
    // do this on mouse enter...
    },
    function() {
    // do this on mouse leave...
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector works, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/5DFLT/

```
#id1, #id2 {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#id2 {background: blue;}

#id1:hover + #id2 {background:green;}
```

But your HTML structure does not correspond to what would be needed for this to work.

`+` means: an element immediately following another element.
`~` means: an element following, needn't be immediately after the first element, another element.

A jQuery alternative, then, would be as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/5DFLT/1/

```
$("#bar").hover(function () {
    $("#background").css("background-color", "green");
}, function () {
    $("#background").css("background-color", "black");
});
```